# Register as a thread local variable

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

In gcc you can declare a thread local variable, for example, as shown below.

```
__thread long thread_local_variable;
```

Also, in gcc you can specify a variable to use a certain register, for example, as shown below.

```
long register_variable asm ("r15" );
```

I want to combine these two concepts, that is, I want to declare a thread local variable that uses a certain register. How can I do that?

Comment: __thread long var asm("r15"); ?

Comment: What happens when `#threads > #cores`?

Comment: Jason: It does not depend upon number of cores. Even say you have one core, you can still have multiple threads and each thread has its own register sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Your example:

```
long register_variable asm ("r15" );
```

is already declaring a thread-local variable, merely due to the fact that each thread has its own set of register values.

There is no possible way to make GCC's global register-storage variables shareable between threads. The fact that this is not well documented speaks to how ill-thought-out and hackish the whole idea of register-storage global variables is...

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it, that couldn't work.

For a thread local variable, each thread needs it's own instance of storage.  There's only a single `r15` register (or one per core. more precisely), so there's simply no place to put the storage for additional threads.

Also, to put it in [GCC's documentation's](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html#Thread_002dLocal) terms:

> The __thread specifier may be used alone, with the extern or static specifiers, but with no other storage class specifier.

`the register` keyword is a storage class specifier, so cannot be used with `__thread`.

Comment: But each thread has its own register sets, which is saved by the scheduler when the thread is interrupted or yield to the kernel and restored when it is rescheduled. Right? Otherwise, you would never be able to run more threads than number of cores.

Comment: @user1018562: _When the address-of operator is applied to a thread-local variable, it is evaluated at run-time and returns the address of the current thread's instance of that variable. An address so obtained may be used by any thread._ **This pretty much excludes the possibility 'thread local registers'**

Comment: @user1018562: I suppose you have a point there. I think one could possibly implement things such that it could work that way. But I imagine that the way that GCC implements register-specific variables probably just doesn't 'fit' well with how GCC implements thread locals. There are a number of limitations and caveats on both types of variables, and the combination of the two extensions probably wasn't seen as important enough for the effort (if it was even considered as a possibility).

Comment: @ArjunShankar: `register`-class variables cannot have their addresses taken, so it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

When threads swap out, they typically save the entire register state of the processor onto a stack somewhere.  When the thread is restored, the register state is read from memory back into the registers.

So, if the language you used allowed it then you could in theory make this work. Each thread would have its own copy of the r15 register while it was running. However...

GCC Thread storage just wasn't designed that way.  It stores the data in RAM somewhere, so you can later pass the pointer to another thread if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of it, you don't need anything special for it. `register` variables always have a lifetime that is the current invocation of the function in which they are defined. These always are "thread local" variables.

The gcc extension `__thread` and the C11 feature `_Thread_local` are completely different concepts. They specify that a variable of static storage is instantiated on a per thread base. These kind of variables are never `register` variables. The `register` keyword in C forbids you to take the address of a variable, and forces the variable otherwise to be similar to `auto` variables.

Comment: I think OP was talking about GCC's register-storage global variables, a GCC extension. These are of course naturally/inherently thread-local since each thread has its own set of registers.